# Viber sync from Mac to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, android

I have been trying to find a way to import my Viber chat from a previous (Android) phone to my latest device (an iPhone), but with no luck at all. I have successfully imported the chat history from the Android on my Mac but I did not find any way to get it on the iPhone.

I have read that Viber messages on IOS are stored on iCloud unlike Android and I thought that maybe thats what will Mac do too and so they will sync to the iPhone but this is not the case. I also found Backuptrans software but I do not want to pay just to get my chat on another device.

I have also seen this [statement](https://help.viber.com/en/article/transfer-your-viber-history-from-one-device-to-another) at [help.viber.com](https://help.viber.com)

> Your Viber account and chat history are connected to the platform that your phone uses, i.e. Android or iOS. **There is no way to transfer content between the two platforms**

But since 3rd party apps offer this functionality there is a way to achieve it.

I am looking for a way to import my chat history from either Mac or Android device to an iPhone.

**Raw ideas or unfinished projects on how it could be done are welcome too and I am willing to contribute.**

Answer (score 0):

From https://help.viber.com/en/article/transfer-your-viber-history-from-one-device-to-another

> Your Viber account and chat history are connected to the platform that your phone uses, i.e. Android or iOS. **There is no way to transfer content between the two platforms**

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I had already seen this,  anyway I edited my question to be more precise.